# Perl substitue function s/// without regular expressions

Tags: perl

I am using the Perl substitute function, s///

My understanding is the first argument is a regular expression.  I am do not want the first argument to be a regular expression.  I want it to be a string.  I do want to escape characters like /, tab, and newline.

The problem is that I have a file.  I want to change a block of text that spans several lines to a different block of text. The text may have /, comma, #, tab and newline characters in it. I have escaped / to /, tab to \t and newline to \n in the input text.

I'm running inside a bash script. The change line is:

```
perl -0777pe "s/# Options\n\t-stdin/# Options\n\t-stdout/g" "$file" >/home/me/"${filename}"
```

the actual input text is much longer, example. Ignore all trailing white space.  findString is one strng.

```
# Usage: \/Users\/mac\/BitHoist-PPC-MacOS-X [options] input... < input > output\n
# Options and inputs may be intermixed\n
\t-stdin     # Use standard input as input file\n
\t-offset nn # Offset next input file data by nn\n
\t           #   Applies to next input specification
```

Comment: Inside Perl, you can use `\Q` to avoid interpretation of special characters. From the shell, you are out of luck.

Comment: I do not mind using some other language/program.Is there someother function than substitute?

Comment: Is there some function I can invoke from the command line to escape a string?  How about in bash?

Comment: perl -e 'print "\Q$ARGV[0]"' "$shellvar"

Comment: me $ echo $shellvar;
my \t \n / /;
me $ perl -e 'print "\Q$ARGV[0]"' "$shellvar";
my\ \\t\ \\n\ \/\ \/;

Comment: Your question is unclear. You're talking about a string giving you a problem, but there are no strings in your program. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

you can use a String instead of a normal regular expression by simple quoting it, e.g. s/\Q$string/.../

Comment: This would work for Perl variables, but for shell variables it is not enough.

Comment: Sure it works with double quotes. But then you have to use `\\Q` instead of `\Q` so the shell does not try to interprete it inside double quotes. But of course it would be bad if the string contains "/", so maybe you give the string as command line argument and access it with `$ARGV[0]` and use single quotes for the perl statement.

Comment: Unfortunatly you cannot have option -pe and the pattern as command line argument :( . In this case you would have to create your `while(<>)` loop yourself and use -e only.

Comment: -pe  I do not know what the -p option does.  I think the -e is for the command line.  Do I need these?

Comment: I do not know Perl.  I am using it over sed, etc. because they do not allow me to cross line ends.  I'd be happy to use sed etc. if possible.

Comment: -e is for statement and -p adds the loop around it, e.g. read, process, print. See man perlrun. sed would probably not solve the problem for you. And with -p you cannot cross line ends either, because this makes the -e statement work on each line.

Comment: Backslash found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "s/\Q### \\/Users\\/mac\"

Comment: like I said, use `\\Q` not `\Q` if you are using double quotes around it. This is not a thing of Perl, but of the shell. And you also tried to escape the final double quote.

Comment: perl -0777pe "s/\\Q${findString}/${replaceString}/g" "$file" >/home/me/BitHoist/test/iout/"${filename}"

Answer (score 1):

Slash, comma, tab (HT) and newline (LF) are not special inside regular expressions. Each of them matches the same character as part of the target string.

Answer (score 0):

This Bash script allows you to change a multi-line string in .c and .h files.  It includes the perl substitute statement I was asking about here.

```
#!/bin/bash 
#-vx

# textChangeMultLine.bash
#
# Changes multiple lines of .c and .h text files in a directory.
# You will need to adjust the input directory and output directeries as needed
#    inputDir 
#    outputDir
# Only changed files are written out to the new directory
#
# The string to change is ${findString}.  They may contain line end characters.
#
# The new string will be ${replaceString}
#
#
# Copyright (C) 2014 Historystamp
#
# textChangeMultLine.bash is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU General Public License, version 2,
# as published by the Free Software Foundation.
# 
# textChangeMultLine.bash is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
# GNU General Public License for more details.
# 
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
# along with BitHoist; see the file License.  If not, write to the
# Free Software Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place, Suite 330,
# Boston, MA  02111-1307  USA.
#
#

# debug info
export PS4='+(${BASH_SOURCE}:${LINENO}):'

# trace all the lines
#set -o xtrace


 inputDir="/home/me/BitHoist/source"

 outputDir="/home/me/BitHoist/test/iout/"

 veryVerbose="no"

# Check for command-line options used when calling the script
if [ $# -gt 0 ] ; then
   while getopts "f:vh" Option ; 
   do
      case "${Option}" in
      f ) inputDir=${OPTARG}
        ;;
      h ) echo "Help" 
         echo "-f <filename>    source directory to read."
         echo "                 You may want to specify the complete path."
         echo "                 default is ${inputDir}"
         echo "                 by the way output is ${outputDir}"
         echo "-h Help which you see" 
         echo "-v    verbose messages."
         echo 
         exit 10
         ;;
      v ) echo "Will display very detailed messages. -v argument used on command line." 
         echo
         veryVerbose="Yes" 
         ;;
      * ) echo "Unknown argument among arguments $* on command line.  Try -h" 
         exit 11
         ;;
      esac
   done
fi


# string to find.
read -d '' findString <<"EOFEOFEOF"
BitHoist is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms of the GNU General Public License, version 2,
as published by the Free Software Foundation.

BitHoist is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
GNU General Public License for more details.

You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
along with BitHoist; see the file License.  If not, write to the
Free Software Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place, Suite 330,
Boston, MA  02111-1307  USA.
EOFEOFEOF

if [ "${veryVerbose}" = "Yes" ]; then
    echo "findString before changes is:"
    echo -n "${findString}" | hexdump -C
  fi

# escape text for Bash.
# change / to //
findString=${findString//\\/\\\\/}
# escape "
findString=${findString//\"/\\\"/}
if [ "${veryVerbose}" = "Yes" ]; then
    echo "changed findString is:"
    echo -n "${findString}" | hexdump -C
  fi
# string to replace
read -d '' replaceString <<"EOFEOFEOF"
GNU General Public License 

This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
the Free Software Foundation,  version 3

This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, 
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
GNU General Public License for more details.

For a copy of the GNU General Public License 
see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
EOFEOFEOF

if [ "${veryVerbose}" = "Yes" ]; then
    echo "replaceString before changes is:"
    echo -n "${replaceString}" | hexdump -C
  fi

replaceString=${replaceString//\"/\\\"/}
replaceString=${replaceString//\\/\\\\/}

if [ "${veryVerbose}" = "Yes" ]
  then
    echo "changed replaceString is:"
    echo -n "${replaceString}" | hexdump -C
  fi


# What files to examine for string replacement
find "${inputDir}" -iname "*.[ch]" | while read file
do
    if [ "${veryVerbose}" = "Yes" ]
      then
        echo 
        echo "file= ${file}" 
      fi

    filename=$(basename "${file}")

    if [ "${veryVerbose}" = "Yes" ]
      then
        echo "filename= ${filename}" 
      fi

    echo -n "${file} "

    rm -f "${outputDir}${filename}"

    # Use perl for the string replacement.  Allows lineend characters in string.
    perl -e '
        $verb = "'"${veryVerbose}"'";
        open  $logfile, "'"${file}"'"; 
        $mydata = "";     
        while ($row = <$logfile>) { $mydata .= $row; }
        close $logfile;
        $originalMydata=$mydata;
        if ( $verb eq "Yes" ) { print "...mydata is \n$mydata\n"; }
        $input = "'"${findString}"'";      
        if ( $verb eq "Yes" ) { print "input = $input\n"; }   
        $output = "'"${replaceString}"'";      
        if ( $verb eq "Yes" ) { print "output = $output\n"; }
        $mydata =~ s/\Q$input/$output/g;
        if ( $verb eq "Yes" ) { print "--->mydata is changed to\n";
                print "$mydata\n"; }
        if ( $originalMydata eq $mydata ) {print "no change.\n";} else 
            { 
            open($fh, ">", "'"${outputDir}${filename}"'") or die "Could not open file $!";
            print $fh "$mydata"; 
            close $fh;
            print "\nUpdated test file: '"${filename}"'\n\n";
            }
        if ( $verb eq "Yes" ) { print "perl complete.\n";} '


    #cmp "$file" "/home/me/BitHoist/test/iout/${filename}"
done


exit
```